# Racket Macro How to Pass Ellipses to Helper function?

Tags: macros, racket, ellipsis

Given:

```
(define-syntax (test stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ body ...)
     (with-syntax ([body0 (process-body #'(body ...))])
       #'body0)]))
```

How should I receive the pattern and the ellipses in the helper?  I'm not even sure if wrapping the body ... inside () is correct, but I've seen it around and it's the only thing that doesn't crash.

The process-body procedure ends up with syntax that has extra () wrapping it.  I can try and break this apart, but I'm just wondering what the correct way to do this is.

process-body wraps the body pattern with some code before AND after.  And, similar to define, I want to be able to provide the macro with multiple forms rather than all forms in one list.  So, if given (form1) (form2), where form2 is the ellipses, process-body should (do-something) (form1) (form2) (do-something-else).

ie,

```
(define-for-syntax (process-body body-syntax)
  (with-syntax ([stx body-syntax])
    (syntax/loc body-syntax
      (λ (request)
         stx))))
```

Of course I have this working when I define the template in-line, and I suppose I could do that here, but sometimes the template becomes unwieldy and it's nice to call a helper.

Thanks a lot.

As an edit to try dyoo's first example, I'm providing the following:

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax (test2 stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ body ...)
     (with-syntax ([(body0 ...) (process-body2 #'(body ...))])
       #'(begin body0 ...))]))

(define-for-syntax (process-body2 bodies)
  (with-syntax ([(body ...) bodies])
    (syntax/loc bodies
      (λ (request)
         body ...))))

(test2 (print "hi"))
```

> > λ: bad syntax

Comment: If `process-body` is intended to consume a list of syntaxes, then you can probably do something like: `(process-body (syntax->list #'(body ...)))`, using `syntax->list` to fragment the syntax object into its pieces.

Comment: Without knowing more information about what `process-body` does, the question is a little unclear.  Can you add more detail?

Comment: Sure thing, I edited it.  Let me know if that makes a bit more sense.  I also did try the (syntax->list), but then not sure how to return the cdr of the list as standalone syntax objects from the helper.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly: can you use `begin` to splice?

Comment: it's the splicing i'm not familiar with.  So, let's say process-body receives a list of stx-objects.  Currently, it just receives one syntax object and returns it as (lambda () (something) stx-obj (something-else)).  What I'd like to do is basically (apply begin stx-list), but that doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The left hand side of a `with-syntax` pattern can also have ellipses, so that the following is possible:

```
(define-syntax (test stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ body ...)
     (with-syntax ([(body0 ...) (process-body #'(body ...))])
       #'(begin body0 ...))]))
```

The basic idea is that if `process-body` returns the transformed body elements, we can then introduce them all together with a `begin`.

---

Your `process-body` definition can also use `with-syntax` with ellipses too.  So you can do something like this:

```
(define-for-syntax (process-body bodies)
  (with-syntax ([(body ...) bodies])
    (syntax/loc bodies
      (λ (request)
         body ...))))
```

If that's the definition of `process-body`, we should amend `test` since the shape of the result from `process-body` is now a complete lambda expression, so we can just return its result directly:

```
(define-syntax (test stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ body ...)
     (process-body (syntax/loc stx (body ...)))]))
```

---

As a self-contained example:

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax (test stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ body ...)
     (process-body 
      (syntax/loc stx (body ...)))]))

(define-for-syntax (process-body bodies)
  (with-syntax ([(body ...) bodies])
    (syntax/loc bodies
      (λ (request)
        (printf "before the body\n")
        body ...
        (printf "after the body\n")))))


;; Let's try it:    
(define p 
  (test (displayln "hello") (displayln "world")))

(p 'should-be-a-request)
```

Comment: Ok, that worked.  I didn't realize that ellipses could go inside the assignment of with-syntax like that.  I was trying to return it just as body0, but then it was complaining there were no ellipses in the template.

Comment: Except, when wrapped in a lambda, I get lambda: bad syntax.  So, if process body is (see the end of the question for an edit).  This is due to the parenthesis wrapping the #'(body...) when passed in I think??

Comment: Basically, what's happening is that the final return value is (lambda (lambda (request) ((my-proc)) with the 2 parenthesis, since the original syntax was wrapped in parens in order to pass in the #'body ... as one arg.  I'm not sure though, brain is starting to seize up ;)

Comment: No problem.  Let me know if the revised answer helps.  Also note the tutorial by Greg Hendershott called "Fear of Macros".  http://www.greghendershott.com/fear-of-macros/

Comment: Same problem, using your edits.  λ: bad syntax.  The test and process-body forms are identical to yours, except that (syntax/loc body-syntax is now replaced with (syntax/loc bodies

Comment: If I remove the ellipses entirely, it works of course.  And the difference is that in wrapping the #'body ... inside (), those extra parens end up in the final syntax, resulting in (lamda (result) ((do something) (do something n+1))

Comment: I'm including a self-contained answer; see if it makes sense.  I still have no idea where you'd see the error you're seeing unless λ were being treated standalone, rather than being at the head of a parenthesized form, or if you were constructing a λ without a variable list, as one of your previous comments suggests.  That is, `(lambda (lambda (request) ((my-proc)))` looks wrong: I expected `(lambda (request) (my-proc))` or something like that: there's one too many `lambda` in there... :)

Comment: Not sure, it's probably a simple error due to the all day coding session of a racket newbie.  I've appended the original question with my own self-contained example that's failing.

Comment: Take a much closer look at my definition of `test`, and note that it does not introduce a `begin` anymore.  The bug is that `test2` is basically constructing the syntax object: `#'(begin λ (request) (print "hi")).`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22729/discussion-between-dyoo-and-scott)